# Change of basis: why is Q an identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Let $\beta$ and $\beta'$ be two ordered bases for a finite-dimensional vector space V, and let Q= $[I_V]^{\beta}_{\beta'}$. Then
>
> a). Q is invertible
>
> b). for any $v \in V$, $[v]_\beta=Q[v]_{\beta'}$

My question is why is Q an identity matrix?

Comment: @Beacon: It can be confusing. And mathematicians are often very lazy about distinguishing between a linear map and the matrix that represents that map w.r.t. a basis (or two bases). Your text seems to be using brackets to mean "representation of a map (or vector) w.r.t. bases", but the bases are frequently implicit or left unmentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to understand what exactly is going on with that bracket notation.  For a transformation $T:V \to W$ and bases $\beta,\beta'$ of $V$ and $W$, $[T]^\beta_{\beta'}$ is defined to be the matrix for which 
$$
[T]^\beta_{\beta'}[v]_{\beta} = [T(v)]_{\beta'}.
$$
Here, $[v]_{\beta}$ denotes the coordinate vector of $v$ relative to the basis $\beta$.  On the other hand, the change of basis matrix $Q$ is defined so that we just get the input with respect to the new basis. In other words, we want $Q$ to satisfy
$$
Q[v]_\beta
 = [v]_{\beta'}.
$$
If we want to replace the $Q$ in this equation with $[T]^\beta_{\beta'}$ for some linear transformation $T$ on $V$, then the only transformation that makes sense is the identity map $I_V$ defined by $I_V(v) = v$.  So, $Q = [I_V]^\beta_{\beta'}$.